# Can we migrate existing project Apache Spark code from azure Databricks cluster to on-prime cluster with same benchmark?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

As per discusses with client.
Our team want to reduce the Dollor cost of Azue cloud regarding Databricks computing.

Is it possible to achive using OpenSource services  [OpenSource Apache Spark + Data Lake Storage Gen2 ] and purchase security license for data governance?

Is it possible, we can use Jupiter Notebook as similar as DataBricks Notebook?

I tried to reduce the cost of my project over a Azure databricks.
But unable to reduce cost of Azure DataBricks cluster.

Comment: This is 100% Doable. But its more complex then you are thinking. You have to take care of a lot of things to build and manage the entire cluster yourself.

Comment: Adding to Daredevil's point - I've seen teams go back to Databricks after they see the TCO is higher running their own cluster and that's before taking extra full stack support staff into the equation.

Comment: There's really no way to know what you can and can't run in your own Spark cluster, as you've shared no specifics of what you're running in Databricks. Have you tried running any of your code locally? If so: what issues have you run into? You can then post a question containing a [mcve] that provides all details. Right now, though, there's no programming question here, and this is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

While Apachy spark is good option, the solution you provided will not give you the same performance as the Databricks especially if you have high workload or complex transformation.
The idea is that Databricks integrates all the underlying layer as one ready solution and give you granular option on the cluster to control its usage and performance.

for example. the DBFS is a temp storage that will be deleted automatically once the workspace is deleted. which reduce the storage cost, and if you used ADLS, you will need to do that manually.

Also you can manage the cluster start/stop operation on demand which is very hard to manage with on-prem compute

furthermore, the compute specs are highly flexible and scalable with Databricks

However, You have many ways to reduce the azure Databricks cluster cost. 
**Way1**: change the cluster instance type. 
**Way2**: Use spot instance 
**Way3**: use interactive clusters with auto-terminate feature 
**way4**: allow autoscale with min and max compute instance 
**way5**: use cluster pools to reduce cluster start and scale-up time

And finally, you can check the ADB [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/cluster-config-best-practices)

Comment: Your answer is good, but it's not exactly answering the question about moving to on-prem. It's probably better as a comment and not an answer.